# Error in Excel formula =if(countif(A:A,B2) > 0,"true","false")

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use formula `=if(countif(A:A,B2) > 0,"true","false")`, but excel giving an error. Also highlight brackets `(A:A,B2)` . What can be the problem here?

Comment: Does your version of Excel perhaps use the semicolon as argument separator in formulas, instead of the comma?

Comment: ^^ Also, you don't need to write "true" nor "false" usually. Just `=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>0` will do where indeed, you may need to swap the comma to a semi-colon.

Comment: Also, don't put True and False in "", they are reserved words understood by Excel and resolve to 1 and 0.

Comment: Thank you all! The reason was in my custom language (english formulas can not work in russian version). And exactly the semicolon was the argument separator in formulas, instead of the comma

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was in my custom language (English formulas can not work in Russian version). And exactly the semicolon was the argument separator in formulas, instead of the comma

To Know more, you can refer https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889

**Manually setting delimiters**

Excel functions **rely on delimiters to separate ranges and arguments** from each other. Different languages use different separators, so while the Functions Translator will try to make the right choices, it may sometimes be necessary to set some of these manually.